# C - fgets and length of stdin

Tags: c, string, fgets

I have written a program in C which lets the user enter a password to let him into the system or not.  I am using the method fgets.  The correct password is "letmein".  This is the code:

Now I want to verify that the password entered by the user through stdin is no longer than 8 characters.  As the program is (without the empty if statement), the user is granted access even if he entered "letmein0000000" since only the first seven characters are fetched by fgets.  Now I only want to grant access to the user if he enters "letmein".  How can this be done please?

P.S. I have to use fgets since it is a requirement in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation for [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. The produced character string is always NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

Request to read a maximum of `8` characters (this means passing `9` as second argument). If the user enters more than `7` characters then it can be caught. Inform user of failure and skip whatever remains in `stdin`. If the user correctly enters `7` and hits return `fgets()` will stop at the new-line character.

Check return value of `fgets()` to ensure the code does not attempt to process an unitialised buffer.

For example:

```
char password[9];

if (fgets(password, 9, stdin))
{
    /* Strip new-line if present. */
    char* nl = strchr(password, '\n');
    if (nl) *nl = 0;

    if (strlen(password) > 7)
    {
        /* Password too long. 
           Skip remaining input if necessary. */
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp("letmein", password))
    {
        /* Good password. */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Incorrect password. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I wanted to say is that how can I be sure that the input provided by the user is no longer than 8 characters (including the null terminating symbol?).  If the user enters "letmein1234", the program will still accept it as a good password since 1234 are truncated by fgets.  How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: @Matthew, maybe I was not clear. My answer is suggesting to instruct `fgets()` to read more than `7`. This means if the user enters `"letmein1234"` then `fgets()` would read `"letmein1"`, the rest of the input is irrelevant. If the user enters `"letmein"` the `fgets()` will stop at the new-line.

Comment: @Matthew: make the buffer big enough to hold the longest line you can reasonably conceive of a user typing (say 1024 bytes), and read it.  Then check whether the length read (after subtracting the newline) is too long; only then check whether the string is equal.  Or, hash what the user entered minus the newline, and compare it with the saved hash; if the string is too long, it won't hash to the correct value, but the user won't have a timing attack on your code.

Comment: get all the line entered by the user up to the newline symbol.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the buffer only needs to be 1 byte too long. Any input after 1 byte too many is uninteresting and the excessive length has been detected.

Comment: Suppose the user types 'Incredibly Long String' as the password.  Suppose you read 1 more byte than the 8 permitted in the password.  The next read operation is going to get 'y Long String' which is probably not what the user intended.  You need to read all the input up to the newline; that's what the user typed.  Then you collect what you're interested in from what the user typed.  And you can tell them, if you like, "what you typed was far too long".  But you must do something about the extra characters that the user typed.  If it was a GUI application, the discussion would be different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I suggested skipping the remaining input if the password is too long as the input is deemed invalid.